# 2D array of objects C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, 2d

I have made this method that creates a 2D array for co-ordinates and places objects (item, treasure, enemy)  in random locations. I want to make a new method that takes in the current Player object (so I can keep the current hp, stats, points) and spawn a set of co-ordinates and objects in random locations.

```
void Game::newGame() {
    srand(time(0));

    int count = 0;
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    Room* newRoom = new Room;
    room = newRoom;
    m_alive = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            room->aRoom[i][j] = NULL;
        }
    }

    //spawn player at 0,0
    room->aRoom[0][0] = new Player("Lemmiwinks", rand()%9+11, rand()%6+7, rand()%6+7);
    m_player = room->aRoom[0][0];
    room->currentRow = 0;
    room->currentCol = 0;
    printMoves();

    //spawn boss
    room->aRoom[rand()%rows][cols-1] = new Boss("Demon Lord", rand()%9 + 10, rand()%7 + 8, rand()%7 + 8);

    //spawn meat cleaver
    count = 0;
    while(count < 1) {
        row = rand()%rows;
        col = rand()%cols;
        if (room->aRoom[row][col] == NULL) {
            room->aRoom[row][col] = new Item("Rusty Shank", 0, 3, 1);
            count++;
        }
    }

    //spawn barrel lid
    count = 0;
    while(count < 1) {
        row = rand()%rows;
        col = rand()%cols;
        if (room->aRoom[row][col] == NULL) {
            room->aRoom[row][col] = new Item("Barrel Lid", 0, 1, 3);
            count++;
        }
    }

    //place potion at random loc
    count = 0;
    while(count < 2) {
        row = rand()%rows;
        col = rand()%cols;
        if (room->aRoom[row][col] == NULL) {
            room->aRoom[row][col] = new Item("Potion", 10, 0, 0);
            count++;
        }
    }   

    //place 5 enemies at random loc
    count = 0;
    while(count < 5) {
        row = rand()%rows;
        col = rand()%cols;
        if (room->aRoom[row][col] == NULL) {
            room->aRoom[row][col] = new Enemy("Demon", rand()%5 + 5, rand()%4 + 4, rand()%4 + 4);
            count++;
        }
    }

    //place 5 treasures at random loc
    count = 0;
    while(count < 5) {
        row = rand()%rows;
        col = rand()%cols;
        if (room->aRoom[row][col] == NULL) {
            room->aRoom[row][col] = new Treasure("Artifact", rand()%5 + 5);
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n---Stats---" << endl;
    m_player->printEntity();

}
```

Is there any way I can dupe this method and pass in a player object so I can reuse the same player on a new map?

Comment: Suggestion: You might want to save yourself from a lot of problems by switching to `std::vector`.

Comment: Did you try passing the `Player` object as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but should do it:

```
void Game::newGame() {

...
    if (!m_player) {
        m_player = new Player("Lemmiwinks", rand()%9+11, rand()%6+7, rand()%6+7);
    }
    room->aRoom[0][0] = m_player; 
...
}

void Room::clear(Item* player) {
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (room->aRoom[i][j] != player) {
                delete room->aRoom[i][j];
            }
            room->aRoom[i][j] = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd consider maybe using smart pointers for your game objects.  Maybe you are already, but I wouldn't be able to tell from you example code.

You could always restructure your program and simply have a list(s) of game objects and each contains its coordinates.  This would save iterating over a potentially large 2d array in the rest of the game logic.  Would also potentially avoid many of the double-dispatches that you'll be having.

Comment: Yep. That one 'if' condition in the first block of code solved my whole problem. Thanks!